# What is the meaning of "Only raw PCM 16 bits mono files with the same frequency as the current voice are supported by the audio tag."?

Tags: html5-audio

When trying to use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag, I get this error:

> Only raw PCM 16 bits mono files with the same frequency as the current
>   voice are supported by the audio tag.

What does this mean?

Comment: This is related to JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `Only raw PCM 16 bits mono files with the same frequency as the current voice` are supported by the HTML 5 `<audio>` tag. Your file is in the wrong format - resample it to a single (mono) channel at, say, 44.1KHz (standard), encoded as 16 bit PCM, and it should play fine.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote **and the comment**. Can someone tell me if I've got anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

is it a wave file? If not you need a put the pcm in to wav file
PCM is the audio format in wav containers. I also think it can be AIFF in wav files but mostly WAV files contain PCM. 
So if the file you are trying to play is not a wav file it might be complaining about that.
Just the extension is wav does not also mean that it is a wav file. The file needs to have wav headers and other stuff that wav would have.